# How to atomic "create if not found" with CouchBase

Tags: atomic, couchbase

For example I want to check if the user input email are already exist or not, then if only not found, save that user object to CouchBase.
Can I do that with N1QL?
Can I do that with this native driver: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/gocb
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be if the email address is the objectID or part of the object ID. If it is, you just do an [insert() with the objectID](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/go-beta/storing.html) and you're done.

If you cannot use the email in the ObjectID, then you will have to do a view or use N1QL. The first one using the ObjectId will of course be the most performant. Key lookups always are.

Comment: How can I do that with view or N1QL? I cannot use email as a part of ID because I allow user to change email later, and we have strict format for object ID

Comment: if you have to use views, you cannot do that atomicly in Couchbase since only document-level operations are atomic. what you can maybe do is have a view that indexes emails + a temporary document with the email as id, that serve as a "transaction" document ensuring that no two processes can check the existence of the email and be answered it doesn't exist (in a race condition): `insert` marker doc (so it will fail if exist) > query the view > if view says 0, create the object, if not abort > in either case delete marker doc